# Как на C++ записать сложную математическую формулу

Tags: c++

Задание, составить программу, которая рассчитывает решение по формуле (прикреплена). Если непонятно, что это за ch1, ch2 и т.д., то для нашего преподавателя нужно, чтобы всё было очень сильно разжевано, поэтому почти каждое действие я писал в отдельных переменных, да и так запутаться труднее, но я смог(
В ответе выдает 6 с лишним, когда должно получиться 5.1507.
З.Ы. где логарифм, там основание 2.5.
Мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    double x, y, z, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5,ch6, ch7,
    ch8, ch9, ch10, ch11, ch12, ch13, ch14;
    std::cout << "Input x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Input y: ";
    std::cin >> y;
    ch1 = pow(x, 2) / 2; // x^2
    ch2 = (1 - cos(2 * pow(x, 3))) / 2; // sin^2(x^3), только другая 
    формула
    ch3 = ch1 - ch2; 
    ch4 = fabs(ch3);
    ch5 = pow(ch4, (1/3.)); // куб. корень из |x^2/2 - sin^2(x^3)|
    ch6 = log10(fabs(x)) / log10(2.5); // log2.5|x|
    ch7 = ch5 * ch6; 
    ch8 = pow(10, cos(y));
    ch9 = ch7 - ch8; // Верхняя часть
    ch10 = pow(2, (x - y)); // 2 ^ (x - y)
    ch11 = 2.5 * fabs(tan(y)); 2.5 * |tg(y)|
    ch12 = sqrt(fabs(x + ch11)); 
    ch13 = ch10 * ch12; // Нижняя часть
    z = ch9 / ch13;
    std::cout << "z = " << z << std::endl;



    return 0;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Посчитайте вручную каждый шаг и сравните результат вашей программы на этом шаге. Пользуйтесь дебаггером

Comment: Не забыли, что аргумент для тригонометрических функций в радианах задается?

Comment: @alexolut, и правда! Спасибо)